# letsencrypt/certbot doesnt find certificate

Tags: certbot

I have expired certificates I want to renew but when i type

```
certbot certificates
```

I get

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
No certificates found.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

I have checked my /etc/letsencrypt/live/ and I do have <mydomain.org> folder.

Certbot is running in a docker container that was stopped and relaunched.

How can I tell my certbot where to find the certificates so it can renew it properly with `certbot renew`?

I have checked the documentation @ https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates but didnt find anything useful

Thank you